# Facebook Canvas Login Helper (v5.0) User has not authorized your app yet

Tags: oauth-2.0, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

Here is what I ended up using in the PHP part:

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/resource/lib/facebook-php-sdk-v4-5.0.0/autoload.php";

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
'app_id' => '{app ID}',
'app_secret' => '{app secret}}',
'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
]);

$helper = $fb->getCanvasHelper();

try {
$access_token = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
// When Graph returns an error
echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
// When validation fails or other local issues
echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
exit;
}

// Logged in
```

And one way to get the user a modal window to allow for the authorization of various permissions is by calling the following function in JS:

```
facebook_authorize = function() {
FB.login(function(response) {
if (response.authResponse) {    
//user has authorized the app     
//redirect or do AJAX call

} 

});    

} else {
//user cancelled login or did not fully authorize
}

}, {scope: 'email, user_hometown, user_location, user_likes'});
return false;    
};

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
appId: '{app ID}',
cookie: true, // This is important, it's not enabled by default
status: true,    
version: 'v2.2'
});
};

(function(d, s, id){
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

The PHP SDK getJavaScriptHelper(); method works in the same way, but I am having a problem with the fact that refreshing the page after authentication causes the following error:

```
Graph returned an error: This authorization code has been used.
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't access the link you posted.

For authentication you can use:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login

If your app is in sandbox you must add users to the app so that they can view/authorize it.
*developers.facebook.com/apps/[app_id]/roles/*

If you want to use dialogs you can use Facebook Javascript SDK that has it built-in.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/examples#login